# How to import medium-sized CSV with a large number of nulls and columns into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, ontology, import-csv

I have to import an existing drug ontology into Neo4j. This ontology is stored in a CSV file; it comprises ~30000 lines and 192 columns per line (i.e. values). The thing is that, out of these 192 columns, the vast majority of them (~170) have null values in nearly all of the lines.

The examples I have come across so far involve much simpler schemas (with 4 or 5 columns). In addition, I have not found any useful insights about how to deal with this type of models. However, I have found information regarding null values in general; nevertheless, as a newcomer to Neo4j, I am not sure what is the best way to get the data in the CSV file imported. As far as I know, these are the alternatives:

1. Importation in stages. According to a webinar in Neo4j official webpage, I could first import the ID column and then, for each column "X" with nulls, filter the non-null values in the X column and dump both columns into a new CSV file. This last operation would lead to a Cypher code similar to the following (assuming all drugs are already imported):

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/user/ontology_with .csv" AS line

MATCH (drug:Drug {id: line.`Class ID`})
MATCH (d:Drug {id: line.`X`})
CREATE (drug)-[:ACTIVATES_DRUG]->(d)
```

2. Using FOR EACH statement, which I believe simplifies the previous operation:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/user/ontology_with .csv" AS line
FOREACH(n IN (CASE WHEN line.activates IS NULL THEN [] ELSE [1] END) |
    MERGE (drug:Drug {id: line.`Class ID`})
    CREATE (n)-[:ACTIVATES_DRUG]->(drug)
)
```

3. Using the batch importer. Although according to the size of the CSV (~30000 lines) this option should be dismissed, could it be beneficial considering the null values?. How would I have to cope with the null values if the best option turns out to be the batch importer?

Taking into consideration the features of my original CSV file, particularly the massive number of columns, which way of importing the data into Neo4j would you suggest? I would appreciate the advice of experts or experienced users of Neo4j.

Comment: Why not import RDF into proper triplestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, it turned out to be a little bit more complicated. Most of the CSV columns stored multivalued relationships, with the values being separated by '|', so I had to adjust the previous answer. Here is an example of such a multivalued relationship, just in case it is useful for anybody else:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///DINTO_CSVLint.csv" AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.`may interact with`, '|') AS ddiDrugs
UNWIND ddiDrugs AS i
MATCH (sourceDrug:Drug {preferredLabel: line.`Preferred Label`})
MATCH (destDrug:Drug {uri: i})
MERGE (sourceDrug)-[r:MAY_INTERACT_WITH]->(destDrug)
RETURN r;
```

I used a similar approach in the remaining relationships.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a similar situation before, and chose to use something closest to your first alternative - though with an unwind statement that made pre-filtering the CSV unnecessary.

Assuming index 0 provided the id for *(drug)* and your nullable ids for *(d)* run from index 1 - 191:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///Users/user/ontology_with .csv" AS line
UNWIND range(1,191) as i
MATCH (drug:Drug {id: line[0]})
MATCH (d:Drug {id: line[i]})
CREATE (drug)-[:ACTIVATES_DRUG]->(d)
```

Null values shouldn't return anything for the *MATCH (d:Drug {id: line[i]})*, and therefore will be skipped.